# checking for an integer in a string (java zybooks)

Tags: java, string, integer

Hello first post here hopefully I'm doing it right. I am currently stuck in a problem figuring out if everything in the string are integers or not. I managed to get the yes for each character of the string checked but each time it loops through each character in string i get a new "yes" and need just a yes if EVERY character in string is an integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userString;
  int i;

  userString = scnr.next();

  for (i = 0; i < userString.length(); ++i) {
     if (Character.isDigit(i) == true) {

     }
     System.out.print("yes");
  }      
}
}
```

If I input "1995" my output is "yesyesyesyes", while I need an output of just "yes".

Comment: "hopefully im doing it right" => Your "question" is hard to read with nearly no punctuation and no uppercase letters and no paragraphs. Additionally, please explain detailed where your program is failing.

Comment: It might be easier to check the opposite and then break the loop. And you should present the result after the loop, not inside it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose there fixed it, first post, didn't think grammar would affect what I was asking too much since only one short paragraph. At the bottom I put where I'm failing and what I need.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Check for the opposite as in checking if its false instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Comment: Yes that is the opposite of true :). The point is that you can break the loop as soon as you get the first false since then the whole string is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `System.out.println` is inside the for loop, that's why the output is "yesyesyesyes" for a four length string.

In this case you can suppose that every character in the string is a digit and check every one until you find one that aren't a digit, let's use a while:

```
    String word = "1992";
    boolean isDigit = true;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < word.length() && isDigit) {
        isDigit = Character.isDigit(word.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }

    if(isDigit) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
```

I suppose that your code is for class so the above example should be enough, but you also could use a more functional approach like:

```
    if(word.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That ran perfectly. Was debating of switching over to while loop and get it to run each character of the string till like you said, one popped out that wasn't a digit but still believed for loop was the way to go. I understood most of your code and will go over and test myself to redo on my own making sure I understood every step.

Comment: That will be error if word = '1992w'. when a char is not digit, you should break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Comms lang, you can use `StringUtils.isNumeric(yourString)`
This will return a boolean value.

OR

if you want to do it your way, try this

```
  userString = scnr.next();
  boolean isStringNumeric=true;

  for (i = 0; i < userString.length(); ++i) {
     isStringNumeric = Character.isDigit(userString[i]);
     if (!isStringNumeric) {
         break;
     }
  } 
 if(isStringNumeric){
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else{
     System.out.println("No");   
}
```

Comment: Haven't been taught that yet! Barely on chapter 4 closest thing we've learned to that I'm assuming is isDigit().

Comment: @EduardoBeltran I added a code that will help you, using your way of coding.

Comment: Tried it out and still not getting the output I need. Tested it out with exampled like "1995!!" and wouldn't output "no", keep getting "yes".

Comment: Please do not write `!= true`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson May I know why not ?
@EduardoBeltran I just tried it in my system and I get `No` as output for String `1995!!` . Try again by copying my code.

Comment: Writing `== false` is clearer and using just the ! is even more clear when dealing with a boolean, `if (!Character.isDigit(i))`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Agreed. But what I have written is not wrong in any way.

Comment: Well, your code contains `Character.isDigit(i)` thats obviously always true. Ofc that won't work.